# jQuery 1.6.2 slideUp() and slideDown() height problem after repeated clicks

Tags: jquery, slidedown, slideup

I have a simple accordion menu I've put together today using the jQuery `slideDown()` and `slideUp()` methods.
Example code:

```
<h1>the header</h1>
<div class='thechild'>
the content
</div>

$(function(){

    $('h1').click(function(){
        var next = $(this).next();
        if (next.is(':visible'))
        {
            next.stop().slideUp();
        }
        else
        {
            next.stop().slideDown();
        }             
        return false;
    });

});
```

This works great, however if you click on one of the `<h1>`'s once then again before the animation completes, you can break the `slideUp()` or `slideDown()` event.
What appears to happen is that the second time you click, it will `slideUp()` to zero height fine but if you are sliding down, it will only slide down to its last previous maximum height - i.e the height `.thechild` was at the last time you interrupted the animation by clicking.

What I need is for one click to slideUp or slideDown `.thechild` as appropriate, and a second click to stop the animation (if running) and slide `.thechild` up. A subsequent third click should slideDown `.thechild` to it's full height, not the height it was at when interrupted at click #2. Hope that all makes sense :)

I'm sure I once had this problem before and solved it somehow, but can't remember (or google) the solution I came up with. Is this just a limitation of those slide methods, and is the workaround to do my own `animate()` calls with some more working out for heights?

I've tried playing around with the various booleans you can pass into `.stop()`, but to no avail. There must be something simple I'm missing, can anyone enlighten me?

jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/cY6kX/

to recreate, double-click on the `<h1>` a bunch of times and watch what happens, then click a few more times to see how it will break like this until you reload the page.

Any pointers greatly appreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `true, true` to the stops to complete the animation in full:

```
$(function(){

    $('h1').click(function(){
        var next = $(this).next();
        if (next.is(':visible'))
        {
            next.stop(true, true).slideUp();
        }
        else
        {
            next.stop(true, true).slideDown();
        }             
        return false;
    });

});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/cY6kX/2/

Comment: I tried (true), (true, false) and (false, false) on the stop. my brain must be tired if it didn't occur to try (true, true) aswell - and even after reading the docs for .stop(). Thanks for pointing out the obvious :)

Comment: @jammypeach no problem ^_^ glad to help :-D

Answer (score 4):

Add `true` to the stop methods. E.g., `stop(true,true)`